# Mongo DB Running find scans redundant indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo DB server V4.0.0, installed on Linux.
I have a collection, named "logs".

I have a Windows Service, running on .NET Framework 4.7.2634.0,
C# driver version 2.5.0.0

So, I have several questions

1. Is it alright, if different machines access Mongo DB with different C# driver versions?
2. Could it be the Mongo Compass 1.23.0 is constantly aggregating on my collections, since
   I have terrible performance, and once I'm shutting it down, the Mongo DB seems to improve significantly.
3. For queries that have failed, because of a timeout, why can't I find the full find syntax and explain in the Mongo DB log?
4. I have several indexes. Among them I have these two

```
{ Section: 1, Headline: 1, Timestamp: -1 }
{ Section: 1, Severity: 1, Timestamp: -1 }
```

I'm performing

```
db.logs.find({ Section: "Machine", Headline: /^Shutdown.*/ }
```

, and in the logs, I'm seeing

```
planSummary: IXSCAN { Section: 1, Headline: 1, Timestamp: -1 },
IXSCAN { Section: 1, Severity: 1, Timestamp: -1 }
```

This is very odd, why does it scan the second index as well (the one with the Severity field), if I'm only filtering the field which is contained in the first index (the Headline field)?

Comment: Your last question is unintelligible, please fix the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have just edited the 4th question, which is actually the most acute one.

Comment: Add full query plan to the question.

Comment: That's what I'm seeing in the logs. Would you like to instruct me how to view the full query plan? When I'm trying the Compass Explain feature, I'm actually getting nothing

Comment: This is a well-documented operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it alright, if different machines access Mongo DB with different C# driver versions?

Yes.

> Could it be the Mongo Compass 1.23.0 is constantly aggregating on my collections, since I have terrible performance, and once I'm shutting it down, the Mongo DB seems to improve significantly.

Enable full query logging to verify the "constantly aggregating on my collections" hypothesis. Assuming this is what is actually happening, use connection metadata to identify which driver is issuing those queries.

> For queries that have failed, because of a timeout, why can't I find the full find syntax and explain in the Mongo DB log?

You haven't enabled query logging or the query didn't make it to the server or you missed it in the log or you looked in the wrong log.